# Speed-up Generator -> List -> CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, elasticsearch, optimization, generator

I need to optimize a process of writing to a CSV file data that I have pulled from Elastic Search, where elasticsearch.helpers.scan builds a generator function with the json/dict data.

```
results = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(es, query=body, index=index)
with io.open(csv_file_name, "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=column_names, delimiter=';')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows([document['_source'] for document in results])
```

I timed things up and found ou that the culprit is:
**"[document['_source'] for document in results]"**

It takes a long, long, long time to go through the generator to unpack it into a list, so that it can be written to the CSV. Someting like 30 seconds for 10k records, which might take hours overall, since in some instances I have to process millons of records (and close to 70 columns/features for each record).

**Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I tried different methods for iterating over the data with (like using a "For" and "next" on the generator) with no significantly better results.**

**Should I pull the data form elastic search in a different way? (other than the scan helper, which returns the generator function)**

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[document['_source'] for document in results]
```

is actually not a generator but a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) that allocates as much memory as needed to fit all of the documents from `results`.

Very likely a faster approach is to actually use a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
(document['_source'] for document in results)
```

Altogether:

```
results = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(es, query=body, index=index)
with io.open(csv_file_name, "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=column_names, delimiter=';')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows((document['_source'] for document in results))
```

Comment: Yes - but the generator that I mentioned was 'results' - the return from elastic search's scan helper. It was what I meant in "Generator -> List -> CSV". 
- Generator: 'results'
- List: built from a list comprehension
- csv: writerows on the file

Comment: My answer is still valid. The likely performance issue was creation of the huge list before writing it to the CSV file.

Comment: @WagnerMortz: I am curious if the change I suggested was indeed the issue. Could you please let us know?

Comment: How about accepting the answer (green tick on the left from the answer) and upvoting it as a token of appreciation?

Comment: done, only the upvote won´t show because of my reputation below 15